# Is there a way to check the aliveness of a DB connection object with the lua-cassandra driver?

Tags: lua, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, lua-cassandra

I'm connecting to cassandra database from Lua using **pure-lua-cassandra** driver. Is there a way to check the aliveness of connection object ? If the connection is still alive or it has become stale .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://thibaultcha.github.io/lua-cassandra/manual/README.md.html), there is no API available to check if the connection is still alive.

If you think it is important, feel free to open a feature request on [the project's GitHub repository](https://github.com/thibaultcha/lua-cassandra/issues). Cheers!

Comment: is there any alternate way to check that ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You will need to reach out to the driver devs. Cheers!